# Closing a Java 8 stream opened by flatMap in case of exception?

Tags: java, exception, java-stream

The Javadoc from `Stream.flatMap (Function <T, Stream<U>> mapper)` states:

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

Nice. But what about exception handling?

Consider the following:

```java
public List<Path> search (List<Path> paths) {
  return paths.stream ()
    .flatMap (dir -> {
      try {
        return Files.list (dir);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException (e);
      }
    })
    .filter (this::mightThrowException)
    .collect (toList ());
}
```

If `Files.list (Path)` throws an exception on the first call, its stream is never opened in the first place, so doesn't need closing. If it throws an exception on a later call, the streams generated from previous calls have all been fully processed and closed by `.flapMap ()` per its specification.

But what happen if the filter throws an exception? We're in the middle of processing a file listing stream, so I guess I need to close something somewhere, but I don't get what exactly. The initial `paths.stream ()` maybe? which would then call the close method on derived streams?

NB: for anyone not familiar with the `Files.list (Path)` static method, it returns a `Stream<Path>` that (unlike most streams) needs to be closed.

Comment: I/O is not a good fit for Streams, as your case demonstrates (though there are other reasons as well).  You are better off using loops for this.

Comment: Simple test: [`Stream.of("").flatMap(x -> Stream.of("").onClose(() -> System.out.println("closed"))).forEach(x -> { throw new RuntimeException(); });`](https://ideone.com/U6IpqL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/stream/ReferencePipeline.java#L271) shows that the `Stream` returned to `flatMap` is immediately wrapped in a try with resources, so it will be closed even if a downstream operation throws an exception.

It might be a good idea to update the `flatMap` javadoc to explicitly state that this will happen.