# Does `onClose` propagates to underlying streams when they are merged?

Tags: java, java-stream, guava, try-with-resources

My code merges (flatmap, concatenate) multiple IO streams into a single stream. Does wrapping that stream with a `resource-with-try` block properly close the underlying streams?

```
public ImmutableListMultiMap<Long, Long> find(long customerId, ImmutableList<Long> itemIds) {
    Stream<List<Long>> chunks =
        Streams.stream(Iterators.partition(itemIds, CHUNK_SIZE));
    return Streams.mapWithIndex(
            chunk,
            (chunk, index) -> {
              System.out.println("reading chunk " + index);
              return ImmutableList.copyOf(chunk);
            })
        .flatMap(
            chunk ->
                findItems(customerId, chunk))
        .collect(toImmutableListMultimap(Pair::getFirst, Pair::getSecond));
}

Stream<Pair<Long, Long>> findItems(Long customerId, ImmutableList<Long> itemIds) {
 return Stream.concat(findBigItems(customerId, itemIds), findSmallItems(customerId, itemIds));
}

Stream<Pair<Long, Long>> findSmallItems(Long customerId, ImmutableList<Long> itemIds) {
 // returns a stream from an IO read
}

Stream<Pair<Long, Long>> findBigItems(Long customerId, ImmutableList<Long> itemIds) {
 // returns a stream from an IO read
}
```

Although there is no `try-with-resource` explicit in the code, `flatMap` should do the same (i.e. closes the resources automatically).

Comment: Adding a log msg to one of your onClose handlers should tell you.

Comment: Currently I see resource leakages. So I don't think the onClose even gets called.

Comment: where is the resource-with-try in your example?

Comment: API doc about [java.util.stream.Stream.concat(Stream, Stream)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream)) says "When the resulting stream is closed, the close handlers for both input streams are invoked." - if you meant `concat`, but you wrote `concatenate`. Didn't find that, so maybe you are referring to some other `Stream`.

Comment: The doc for `flatMap()` also says: *Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.* Unclear what happens if the stream is not fully consumed, but you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: `close()` calls `onClose((`, and both propagate to substreams. However iterating a stream to the end doesn't close it.

Comment: @cyberbrain that was typo in the code. fixed it.

Comment: @user207421 It does close flattened substreams.

Comment: Regarding whether `flatMap` closes the stream when it's not fully consumed. It seems that it does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118801/closing-a-java-8-stream-opened-by-flatmap-in-case-of-exception

Comment: Your first statement is self-referential btw. And the second statement references a non-existent `chunk`. So does `findItems()`. It would help to include a compilable sample.

Comment: Fix the first one. Not sure about why you say `findItems()` is non-existent. Is it still a problem?

Comment: Your first sentence mentions IO streams, but you don't mean IO streams, do you?

Comment: Also, shmosel's comment that your first statement is self-referential, and your second statement references a non-existent `chunk`, is still a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and as I hinted in the comments you only need to add a little logging to confirm:

```
.onClose(() -> System.out.println("onClose was called"))
```

Here is a contrived example stream:

```
static Stream<Integer> newStream() {
    return IntStream.range(0,2).boxed()
            .onClose(() -> System.out.println("onClose newStream"))
            .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(i, i+1).onClose(() -> System.out.println("onClose flatMap Stream.of i="+i)));
}
```

If you run this stream with following, you can see when the "onClose" calls are used - or not:

```
System.out.println("TEST1 "+newStream().count());
System.out.println("===");

try(Stream<Integer> stream = newStream()) {
    System.out.println("TEST2 "+stream.count());
}
System.out.println("===");

try(Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.concat(newStream(), newStream())
            .onClose(() -> System.out.println("onClose Stream.concat"))) {
    System.out.println("TEST3 "+stream.count());
}
```

TEST1 isn't inside try-with-resources and misses some of the onClose, but runs the flatMap streams onClose. TEST2/3 print all the onClose calls as expected:

```
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=0
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=1
TEST1 4
===
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=0
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=1
TEST2 4
onClose newStream
===
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=0
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=1
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=0
onClose flatMap Stream.of i=1
TEST3 8
onClose newStream
onClose newStream
onClose Stream.concat
```